# IIS URL Rewrite Module Canonical Link Only If No Subdomain

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am using the IIS URL Rewrite module on a Windows 2012 server. I only want to add a canonical www rule if a subdomain is missing (or an exact match on 'example.com').

The problem is the ready-made Canonical rewrite rule IIS creates rewrites all traffic (*) for all subdomains to www.

```
 <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
 <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
 </rule>
```

The problem is that I have multiple subdomains / applications under one site (and therefore one web.config).

I want

> example.com

to go to

> www.example.com

but to leave these and any other subdomain alone:

> secure.example.com
>
> profile.example.com

Do I need a more specific match regex or pattern?

More specifically, the secure subdomain uses https and a better encryption certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for *everything* that is *not* `www.example.com`. And that includes all other sub-domains.

Let's have a look at your condition:

```
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
```

- If `www.example.com` comes in --> match = true --> negate --> false --> nothing is changed (as you want)
- If `example.com` comes in --> match = false --> negate --> true --> URL gets redirected (as you want)
- If `foo.example.com` comes in --> match = false --> negate --> true --> URL get redirected (as you don't want)

To fix this, try this configuration:

```
<rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
       <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The `C:1` part is for the protocol (`http` and `https`).

Found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-rewrite-protocol-http-https-in-the-action).

Comment: What do you think about Nir's suggestion of this regex: ^(w{3}\.)?\w+\.com/ ? This works, but I am curious if that would make this better.

Comment: That does not seem to work when I go to example.com/dir/something. It doesnt redirect that route to the www subdomain.

Comment: Not sure if it's better or not. There is certainly more than one way to do it. That solution works for me. If you want to dig further, could you provide more information, e.g. some log entries?

Comment: We solved it by using a negate pattern: <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^secure\.example\.com$" negate="true" />

Answer (score 0):

This regex is better:

```
^(w{3}\.)?\w+\.com/
```

This regex will give you the option to get url with and without the www. and the / at the end, but still wont math a subdomain.

Comment: Where would that go? In the match or the pattern?